# Can i mount this to metal studs?

Tags: mounting, studs, hanging

I mounted my TV (about 62lbs) to my apartment’s metal studs using zip toggles. Wondering if I can do so for this wall-mounted work bench too. It weighs about 95lbs.
[Product link](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Lifetime-47-in-L-x-31-in-D-x-60-5-71-5-in-H-Wall-Mounted-Folding-Work-Table-80421/300061152?g_store=&source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D59S-023_008_MOVING_GARAGE-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-D59S-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-FY23_Shopping_Class8&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-CDP-GGL-D59S-023_008_MOVING_GARAGE-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-D59S-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-FY23_Shopping_Class8-71700000108162603-58700008320585090-92700075638267886&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA7t6sBhAiEiwAsaieYovdSkKtzjM3xe8RSHTNcc63AMlrqeB3Z2l12m1Y1K3EBbmvS9ECfhoCwyQQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: The bench looks pretty good about avoiding tension on the anchor and just imposing shear. What's the shear capacity for each anchor installed with your drywall thickness (the supplier probably doesn't publish metal stud values)? Those shear values are probably adequate, and they're intuitively a lower bound on the strength to expect when anchoring to the metal studs.

Comment: It looks like it might be fastened in at least 4 places, which helps.

Comment: @popham yes they are rated at 230 or so pounds each, and there are 4. I’m not as worried about the toggles failing as I am about the possibility of the studs buckling

Comment: Technically the IBC only calls for a bare minimum interior wall to resist a 5 psf pressure (see [IBC 1607.16](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IBC2021P2/chapter-16-structural-design#IBC2021P2_Ch16_Sec1607.16)). For a 7 ft tall wall with studs on 16" centers, that's 50# uniformly distributed on each stud. Could such a wall resist 200# or 300# of shear applied at the wall surface? I'm doubtful. Without more information about the wall, all I can say is that a load bearing wall should be fine and an exterior wall subject to wind loading should be fine.

Comment: For flimsy metal studs, "web crippling" is the probable limit state determining the wall's compression strength. I think it's probably fine, although I'm biased to expect steel stud wall quality that you would encounter in commercial construction.

Comment: 1/4" Snaptoggles are rated to 106 or 116 lbs when installed in ½" or ⅝" drywall (respectively) with 25 gauge steel studs. That's including the REQUIRED 4:1 safety factor that the manufacturer calls for. I'm not sure where you're getting 230 lbs from, but I don't think you understand the load ratings..